# Información Actualizada Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, chromedriver

Utilizo Selenium y ChromeDriver en Python para poder obtener información de una web. La información de esta web es bastante dinámica y es actualizada frecuentemente.

He lanzado el script por primera vez y me muestra la información correcta. Pasado un tiempo, 24 horas; la información de la web ha sufrido cambios, lo visito con un navegador y todo OK. Si lanzo mi script, me muestra la misma información que me mostraba hace 24 horas.

En un principio he pensado que podría ser que la información se encontrara cacheada y por eso me mostrara una información desactualizada; pero parece que no es el caso, ya que la función `driver.quit()` se encarga de cerrar todo y borrar caches.

Al lanzar el script creo el driver con 
`driver = webdriver.Chrome(path_driver,options=chromeOptions)`
y me encargo de cerrarlo con
`driver.quit()`
después ya trabajo la información en estructuras de memoria.

No tengo claro el script de dónde coge la información, ya que parece que hay algún punto intermedio u alguna cache; ya que desde un navegador es capaz de mostrar la información 'actualizada'.

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1):

Has intentado deshabilitar el cache al inicializar chromedriver?

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-application-cache')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```